# Root-NFS: No NFS server available, giving up. VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy. Gem5 X86 in Full system mode error

Tags: gem5

I'm trying to simulate gem5 x86 in full simulation mode but when running command
*telnet 127.0.0.1 3456* got error
**Root-NFS: No NFS server available, giving up.
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Insert root floppy and press ENTER**
and when press enter **VFS: Cannot open root device "hda1" or unknown-block(2,0) and Kernel panic**.
How i can solve this error? if this can be solve by changing root device "hda1" then how i will change it?
I'm attaching screenshot of this.[image]
Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Please learn how to format posts on SO a bit better, and once again, copy paste terminal text instead of images. Read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0/1048477#1048477 and then set the `root=` kernel CLI argument accordingly.

Comment: I tried all the method still not able to fix the error.